# How to update a website (git deploy) keeping the work tree 'dirty'

Tags: git, web-deployment

I have this **remote** tree and git still is not in use:

```
www
    img
        i1.jpg
        i2.jpg
        other.jpg
```

But in my **local** git repo i have this:

```
www
    img
        i1.jpg
        i2.jpg
```

Note i have no 'other.jpg' file.

I am using git to auto deploy the website that i have in local host. I am using [this](http://cuppster.com/2011/01/30/using-git-to-remotely-install-website-updates/) technique.

But, when i do my first `git push web` every 'dirty' file on remote is deleted. It means that the 'other.jpg' file i had not in my local working repo is deleted on remote. But it occurs just in the first time. If i create a new 'otherfile on remote repo (say using ftp, for example) and i `git push web` again, it does not happen again. The new 'otherfile' is not deleted of remote this time.

My question: Is there a way to make a git deploy **keeping** every remote file that is not in my local repo?

I tryed to find something in `git checkout --help` but i could not. I also tryed questions like 'git checkout keeping work tree' on google but with no results too.

Any help would be welcome.
Thank you so much.

Note: I just deleted an 'images' dir of a customer doing a git deploy cause that dir was not in my loca repo! (hoping that hostgator has at least a 7day backup!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
git ls-files --full-name | xargs -n 1 git checkout --
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Does it mean that i should change `git checkout -f` on post-receive hook for that you answered?

Comment: Ok, as fast as possible i will try it. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `git archive` could make the job easier, no?